# How to reduce redundancy in a service implemented using multilayer architecture while maintaining consistency across the system?

Tags: spring, web-services, jakarta-ee, architecture

Currently our service is implemented using a multilayer architecture dividing the whole service into three:

- API
- Business
- Persistence

However this introduces a lot of redundancy within our system. A common adage in the industry is "DRY" (Don't Repeat Yourself). The redundancy has increased the development time, and made the system more fragile and cluttered our code with "copy" methods.

To give a better idea, say we have a `Person` service. This would require the following:

- `Person` entity - JPA annotated class for ORM
- Repository service request - contains field values to be persisted of the Person domain object with additional persistence options
- Repository service response - contains field values of the Person entity
- `Person` - class with business logic, domain fields and computed fields
- Domain service request - contains field values of `Person` resource and additional business options
- Domain service response - contains field values of `Person` business object excluding those that shouldn't be visible to API users
- `Person` resource - class representing what should be viewable to the API users

And things get worse when taking nested objects into consideration.

The current design facilitates difference between concerns (business, API, persistence), however:

- Currently, the differences are very small. This is causing us to have
  very similar classes with only minor differences
- Services returning
  service response objects with fields instead of just the objects
  itself hampers other services from depending on other services

Questions:

- Is it worth it to go through with this design?
- What are our alternatives?
- What could we change to improve our situation?

Answer (score 2):

I know where you're coming from. My shortest advice would be: read ["Domain Driven Desing - Tackling Complexity Inside the Heart of Software"](http://dddcommunity.org/book/evans_2003/) by Eric Evans.

A central part of the DDD is the domain: POJOs containing majority of the business logic.
The building blocks are more or less what you've already mentioned.

There are three kinds of services:

- Application Services that are responsible for orchestration, transaction management and authorization
- Domain Services contain business logic that doesn't fit other domain building blocks: entities, policies, factories, value objects. Create them **only** if you can't use other domain mechanisms.
- Infrastructure Services. The most common are repositories which are responsible for persistence of root aggregates (this role play some of the entities), and **only** them. This is contrast with DAOs which are created for any entity. Other infrastructure services might be for instance clients of Web Services that are being used by the application.

This richness of different kinds of services together with the idea of pushing the logic down as far as possible, because the logic in the domain is the most easily reusable, gives the developers tools they need to build comprehensive and maintainable complex software. Note that DDD might be too heavy for simple CRUD apps.

The entry points to the system are either Web Services endpoints or controllers (for Web apps where UI is generated on the backend like in case of JSPs of JSFs).

For the middle sized systems I like to use approach inspired by CQRS, that is, in order to avoid inevitable slowness when loading multiple root aggregates for displaying purposes (read side) I write dedicated query services that return DTOs straight from the DB, in case of JPA using `select new` mechanism.